# PHP Mail Script not sending mail and solution not covered by conde explanation

Tags: php, email

Got an issue with this mail php script that is not sending the mail, I have tested the server with a simple php mail test script which works fine so that leads me to believe it's something to do with this coding.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact-form" class="row style1" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="number" type="text" id="number" placeholder="Your number" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <textarea name="message" rows="4" class="h130" id="message" placeholder="Write your message..." required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="col-md-9"><p>* When do you want to <strong>reserve the cottage</strong>, please write date, time and number of guests into your message.</p><p><a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions/Privacy</a></p></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right">
        <input class="submit btn" type="submit" value="Send a message" />
        <input class="modal btn hidden" type="button" value="Send a message" name="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBox" />
    </div>

    <!-- Modal window -->
    <div class="modal fade bs-modal-md" id="modalBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact form</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

//******** Email settings ********//
//your email
$email_to = "myemail@mydomain.com";
//subject of email
$email_subject = "Message from website";
//message after success send mail
$email_send = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
<strong>Contact form was sent successfully.</strong>
<br/>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</div>";

if($_POST) {
    //******** Email data ********//
    $cust_name = $_POST['name'];
    $cust_number = $_POST['number'];
    $cust_email = $_POST['email'];
    $cust_message = $_POST['message'];

    $header = "From:" . $cust_email . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
    $header .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $body  = "<strong>Customer email:</strong> " . $cust_email . "<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Customer number:</strong> " . $cust_number . "<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Customer name:</strong> " . $cust_name . "<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Message:</strong> " . $cust_message;

    if($cust_name && $cust_number && $cust_email && mail($email_to, $email_subject, $body, $header)) {
        echo $email_send;
        echo '<script>$("#contact-form").each(function(){
                    this.reset();
                });
              </script>';
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>Error sending mail. Please fill the contact form correctly or contact website administrator.</strong></div>";
    }
}

?>
```

**JS**

```
 /* Contact Form Script */
$("#contact-form").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".modal.btn").click();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send-contact-form.php",
        data: $('#contact-form').serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
    });
});
});
```

When sending email everything works fine, i.e. the modal window pops up saying email sent etc. Probably there is just no email being received.

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Do you get any errors in the html section in your developers tools console in your browser after you submit the form?

Comment: Hi Larry no errors email appears to be sent ok

Comment: Is this php code running on a local host machine or on a live server?

Comment: Live server, which I have tested with a small php mail script and mail was received ok

Comment: I will try and duplicate your results and see if I can figure it out. let me know if you find any errors.